# How to test AWS Batch boto3/moto mocks without running docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, boto3, moto

`moto` currently allows for very powerful tests by emulating Lambda, Batch and other services through Docker. One con of this is requirement for availability of `docker` and slow tests (single `submit_job` test with docker runs in around 2 seconds).

Is there a way to ignore docker when running `moto` mocks and shim/stub docker support by answering "This job is submitted"?

Comment: Dear editors: `moto` and `boto3` are python libraries, there's no need to remove `python` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moto maintainer here. <s>There is no build-in way for moto to run those services without `docker` atm.</s>

It sounds like a useful feature though, so if you feel like it, PR's are always welcome.

Edit on 20/09/2022:
As of Moto 3.1.8, you can use `@batch_simple` to mock the Batch service without running Docker in the background.
See http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/batch.html

Comment: Thanks much! Btw, `moto` is great :) super useful.